# how to specify the color bar values for two csv files in plotly

Tags: plotly, choropleth

I am trying to compare between two datasets. but when I plot it in choropleth map using plotly I have two similar results regardless of the count. Is there any way to specify fixed values in the color bar? or have an intervals as scale/representation of the data?
my intention is to compare between 2 jobs in us states and I want to see how they are related to states
here is my reuslts
[image: dataset1]
[image: dataset2]